Angular 16: Setting Up Multiple Modules with Different Templates and Resource Loading Issues
I am a beginner in Angular and would like to set up two modules: one for Admin with an Admin template and the other module with another Bootstrap template. My concern here is that I realize my pages load their resources from the index.html file, and the two templates cannot fully share this file without risking conflicts, especially with style.css and bootstrap.css files.
So I was wondering if my challenge is possible, if so, how can it be done.
Could you provide me with some guidance on this?
